# Serving searchable PDFs with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, solr, sunspot

Starting work on a project archiving thousands of PDF "reports". Investigating alternatives for making them searchable. Would like users to be able to enter a search term and be presented with a list of reports containing said search term that they can click on and view in their browser. Simple enough.

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) seems to be the most popular option I can find with PDF support...but we don't know Java...So, looking for examples (or just advice) of how to get this working with Rails/[Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/). After a cursory overview it looks fairly complex (requiring esoteric combination of Tika, Solr Cell, Sunspot & Solr itself. Though perhaps (read: hopefully) I'm wrong?!?).

Nutshell: we'd like to point whatever search engine we use to the folders containing the PDFs, let it index them. Then from within a Rails app we can present a search dialog & manage the queries & results.

Options? Degree of difficulty? Advice? Tips?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post: [How to index file contents like pdf, doc, etc.. with Solr, Sunspot, Paperclip, S3 and Rails 3](http://www.chebyte.com/2011/08/13/how-to-index-file-contents-like-pdf-doc-etc-with-solr-sunspot-paperclip-s3-and-rails-3/) that shows some pretty detailed steps for setting this all up.

Answer (score 0):

Lucid Imagination seems to have covered this topic in a nice tutorial: http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/02/17/acts_as_solr_cell/

Comment: Thanks! It looks a bit dated...but I'll look through it for any nuggets.